# oracle, accessing to a member function from a view

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

Firstly, I have this object created by the system :

```
create or replace 
type type_client (
  num int ,
  username varchar(30),
  balance int,
  ta table_achat,
  ref_admin ref type_admin,

  member function get_prix_achat_total return int
);
```

And I have a table of this object created by the system:

```
create table table_client of type_client
```

And a view also created by the system (it gives each user to select his proper line
from table_client):

```
create view one_line_client as 
select * from table_client
where username = (select user from dual);
```

Then I give a user called *`c##client1`* -for example- a privilege to access to this view.

My problem is, the user *`c##client1`* can access all data of type `type_client`
except for the member function ;

When I do

```
select balance from system.one_line_client;
```

or

```
select num from system.one_line_client;
```

then I get the correct result.

But when I do

```
select olc.get_prix_achat_total() from system.one_line_client olc;
```

then I get the error :

> ORA-00904: "OOO"."GET_PRIX_ACHAT_TOTAL": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Off topic, but why are you creating objects in the SYSTEM schema?  Bad.

Comment: please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asterisk does not mean *everything*, it is the ["all-column wildcard"](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55275).  Member functions must be explicitly listed as a column expression in order to show up in the view:

```
create view one_line_client as 
select t.*, 
       t.get_prix_achat_total() as get_prix_achat_total 
from table_client t
where username = (select user from dual);
```

That column expression will indirectly call the function.  It must not use parentheses when it is selected from the view:

```
select olc.get_prix_achat_total from one_line_client olc;
```